# Android - Google has not yet processed your app - I haven't used any Content Providers in my App

Tags: android, indexing, web-crawler, deep-linking

Google has not yet processed your app - I haven't used any Content Providers in my App and I don't need to

There must be a way to do this...

Please Help me in Indexing my App

Following is What I have used to Index my App on Google...

package: com.SmartBloodDonor.blood

website: [www.smartblooddonor.com](http://smartblooddonor.com)

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--
          ATTENTION: This intent was auto-generated. Follow instructions at
          https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio to publish your Android app deep links.
        -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!--
              ATTENTION: This data URL was auto-generated. We recommend that you use the HTTP scheme.
              TODO: Change the host or pathPrefix as necessary.
            -->
            <data
                android:host="www.smartblooddonor.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/main"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.SmartBloodDonor.blood/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.SmartBloodDonor.blood/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}
```

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
    applicationId "com.SmartBloodDonor.blood"

    dependencies {
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
         compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
         compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
     }
```

and finally my **sitemap.xml** I'm using on my website and Google Webmaster

```
    <urlset
        xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <url>
            <loc>blood://donation</loc>
                <xhtml:link
                    rel="alternate"
                    href="android-app://com.SmartBloodDonor.blood/blood/donation" />
        </url>
    </urlset>
```

I tried to **Fetch as Google** in two ways

*Error #1*

```
    URI unsupported
    The associated URL failed to launch the application, because the app URI        
      does not match a supported intent URI in the manifest. Learn more
    APK version: Local upload - app-release.apk [3/15/16, 7:56 AM]
    Fetched URI: android-app://com.SmartBloodDonor.blood/http/www.smartblooddonor.com
```

*Error #2*

```
    URI unsupported
    The associated URL failed to launch the application, because the app URI 
      does not match a supported intent URI in the manifest. Learn more
    APK version: Local upload - app-release.apk [3/15/16, 7:56 AM]
    Fetched URI: android-app://com.SmartBloodDonor.blood/blood/donation
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you didn't quite make it to the end of the implementation process...all that code in **MainActivity.class** is placeholder stuff. There are a number of pieces you still need to fill in manually (all indicated with `TODO`) but the one that is specifically causing you trouble in the verification step is `android-app://com.SmartBloodDonor.blood/http/host/path`. That doesn't match up with what you have in **sitemap.xml** (`android-app://com.SmartBloodDonor.blood/blood/donation`). Try updating the first one.

If you prefer not to deal with the technical stuff, [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I work with the team) can index all your content and take care of the sitemap generation automatically. You even get automatic deep linking thrown in!

Comment: I have tried this, signed up... I did not quite understand the JavaScript part... I have added it to the my website on head tag inside script tag... but it ain't working

Comment: @SmartBloodDonor hmm...could you point me to the documentation page that shows the JavaScript you added to your website? I want to make sure I can see exactly what might be causing the trouble.

Comment: I cant find it again
but i have the code
      var fallbackFunction = function() {
        window.location.replace('market://details?id=com.SmartBloodDonor.blood');
      };
      var addIFrame = function() {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.style.border = "none";
        iframe.style.width = "1px";
        iframe.style.height = "1px";
        iframe.src = 'android.SmartBloodDonor.com://';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      };
      addIFrame();
      setTimeout(fallbackFunction, 250);

Comment: @SmartBloodDonor that doesn't look like any Branch code I'm familiar with. Is that where you got it from? Are you trying to implement deep linking (the app opens when you click a link) or app indexing (content results from inside your app show up on Google searches)?

Comment: my main motive was to index my app for Google search.... I just followed the link you gave and did the steps... one of which was this JS code... if you have any alternative link that takes me exactly to steps for indexing the app into Google search... that would be better... I am not familiar with JS completely but basics... so I have no idea what I was doing with that JS code

Comment: may I contact you via e-mail or something else?

Comment: @SmartBloodDonor Google content indexing is a brand new feature we're just in the process of launching this week. Feel free to submit a support ticket here! https://support.branch.io/